# Как удалить пробелы из предложения?

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть `list`, элементы которого - это предложения. Как в каждом предложении убрать пробелы?

Comment: Покажи пример кода.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что в нём отсутствует важная деталь, без которой нельзя дать хороший ответ. Пожалуйста, редактируйте свой вопрос, добавив в него свой код, чтобы пользователи смогли дать лаконичный ответ. Чтобы редактировать вопрос, нажмите на кнопку [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как задать хороший вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/147382)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = ['Hello, world', 'Goodbye, world']
>>> l = [s.replace(' ', '') for s in l]
>>> l
['Hello,world', 'Goodbye,world']
>>>
```